# Window clearInterval() working without parameter

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer, clearinterval

In some code I found method like this:

```
 scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
            clearInterval();
        });
```

As You see the `clearInterval()` is not receiving any parameters.

[clearInterval() documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) states that parameter is required.
So why this code is working in `google chrome` and throwing `parameter is not optional` in `Internet Explorer 11`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Internet Explorer.

The [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#dom-windowtimers-clearinterval) says:

> If handle does not identify an entry in the list of active timers of the WindowTimers object on which the method was invoked, the method does nothing.

The `undefined` value will not identify an entry in the list of active timers.

Comment: thx. If we pass no value to the method and it will do nothing. What is the point of calling it?  So that this line can be commented out and everything should work fine?